# Sending jquery ajax authentication request to glassfish server fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, glassfish, basic-authentication

I am trying to send an auth request to a servlet hosted by glassfish server 4, receiving back a message in plain text.

The servlet is configured for a BASIC authentication with CONFIDENTIAL transport (https)
(The authentication and the servlet answer work by visiting the page with a web browser)

Here is the jquery script using ajax:

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://192.168.146.128:8181/path_to_servlet",
    dataType: 'text',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));
    },
    async: false,
    success: function (data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

and the servlet code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("hello");
    out.close();

}
```

The problem is that the request don't get any answer of any type (tryied on IE, chrome and firefox with the same result).

What should I do? Is this the right way to authenticate?
And do I need to send the header authorization request with every further request?

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery .ajax object allows for "username" and "password" properties, don't try to hard-code your authorization header.

Per the HTTP spec, you send a request for the data, IF it is secured you get an access denied response, to which you reply with the Authorization header.

If it doesn't work when you access it manually than your server is probably misconfigured sending the client a Access-Control-Allow-Headers header that doesn't have the Authorization header allowed. If it works when you are doing it manually (not using Ajax) than it's likely a cross domain issue, perhaps you could check the error console or dev tools of the browser your using to check the request's response or any warning/errors that are thrown.